# Dual booting Linux Mint 19 and Windows 10, W10 not seeing repartioned drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, multi-boot, linux-mint

Alright, lemme explain my title so it actually makes sense. I'm dual booting LM 19 and Windows 10 on my laptop, and while everything works fine and boots up, there's a slight problem on the Windows 10 side.

It's not "realizing" that the drive has been repartioned, and is still showing the full hard drive as being available instead of the half of it that actually formatted for Windows use. Should I restart from scratch, maybe with a different distro?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check with `fdisk -l` if the partition table has been updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

After running chkdsk /f, it seems to have fixed itself, not sure if it was that which fixed it or something else. Thanks anyway guys!